# Is there an universal term for difference of transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, arithmetic-geometry

Tl;dr: What is the universal name for $C$ when comparing two transformations in $C = B * A^{-1}$, assuming C is a transformation itself?

---

I'm looking into comparing two transformations and extract a transformation that allows me to go from one to the other. But I don't know what to call this.

In 3D graphics I see the word "delta" used a lot to mean a difference of position of vectors. So the delta from position $A$ to position $B$ is the vector $AB$ obtained through $B-A$. But this is a comparison of an additive property to used for Translation.

What if, instead I compare two positions to extract a Scaling transformation between them? The "difference" (?) is not additive but multiplicative. Assuming two co-linear vectors, the Scaling to be applied to position $A$ to become position $B$ is like asking the question: "If position $A$ were to be the multiplicative identity instead of $1$, how much would $B$ be?". Which is obtained with $B/A$.

And the same can be applied to a "pack" of transformations like a Matrix. So I like to think about these as looking to one matrix from the "spacial context" (?) of another matrix, instead of the default identity, correct? If I put matrix $B$ in the context of matrix $A$ I do something like $C = B * A^{-1}$.  What do I call $C$ then? The matrix delta? Or is there another better suited universal name for these type of transformations comparison and extraction of the difference (which is a transformation itself)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would call these the *relative* position/scale/transformation/etc. of $B$ with respect to $A$.

Comment: @Rahul I've bee using something like "Putting $B$ in the context o $A$" maybe because in my area of application there's "objects" so each works as a individual "context". I guess I could say "Making $B$ relative to $A$". Does "Reference Frame" have anything to with this?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_reference

Comment: [Sure.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_velocity)